# Using Scrypted with Google Device Access - permission always expires after a week

Tags: nest-device-access

I use Scrypted to allow viewing Nest cameras in HomeKit. When I go through the process of giving Scrypted permission to access my camera information, that token seems to expire after a week (approximately). I haven't seen any setting anywhere that allows me to change this. Is there some hidden option somewhere that can allow this permission to not expire.

I finally found the expiration page - but I don't see how to remove the 7 day limit. It offers to raise the daily token limit, but not to remove expiration.

[image: Expiration on Google Cloud]

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration this is because your oauth client id is unverified. You'll need to go through the oauth client verification process to get longer lived tokens.

Comment: Can you please explain more? The application is Scrypted - I can't do anything on that item. I am just allowing Scrypted Device Access to have access to my nest cameras. Eg, when I open https://nestservices.google.com/partnerconnections, I see Scrypted. I don't see any options for me to change my "oath client id" to be verified. What is my oauth client id? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. In order to make this authorization permanent, the GCP app that you create needs to be in production, which is set on the OAuth Consent screen.
Here is the conversation on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Scrypted/comments/17tq8nf/google_device_access_weekly_logout/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3